# Trying to calculate the moving average of EEG csv file. Working with minor sample of data - no luck

Tags: list-manipulation

I've been trying out mathematica for data manipulation of some EEG samples I have. Trying to get a moving average of small sample size but nothing changes. Any suggestions?

[image]
[image]

```
trA[[All]] = MovingAverage[sampledata2[[All]], 1]                  
{{4215.74, 6637.71}, {4195.87, 6632.52}, {4227.16, 6640.99}, {4249.27,6641.33}, {4224.84, 6630.44}}
```

Answer (score 3):

The average of one item is itself. Your moving average is calling for averaging one item at a time so it correctly gives the list you gave it back to you.

It is easy to what is happening when you give `MovingAverage` symbolic data.

```
data = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g};

MovingAverage[data, 1]
```

> ```
> {a, b, c, d, e, f, g}
> ```

```
MovingAverage[data, 2]
```

> ```
> {(a + b)/2, (b + c)/2, (c + d)/2, (d + e)/2, (e + f)/2, (f + g)/2}
> ```

```
MovingAverage[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}, {1/2, 1/2}]
```

> ```
> {a/2 + b/2, b/2 + c/2, c/2 + d/2, d/2 + e/2, e/2 + f/2, f/2 + g/2}
> ```

The result of evaluating the expression with two equal weights is interesting because, although it gives a result that is mathematically equivalent to `MovingAverage[data, 2]`, it is expressed differently, suggesting that the computation was perform differently.